# :hover ignored over margin

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover, margin

Strange hover problem in IE8 & 10, about which I can't find anything...  Surely, I'm not the first to stumble upon it?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgSY8/)

```
HTML:
<a href="#"><img style="border:0" src="image.png">Text</a>

CSS:
a {border:1px solid silver}
a img {margin-right:30px}
a:hover {border:1px solid red}
```

In IE, when I hover the mouse over the image or the text, the border changes to red as expected, but when I move the mouse over the space caused by the `margin-right`, the border returns to gray.

In Firefox, the border always stays red wherever the mouse is over the `<a>`.

Since the problem is reproducible on jsFiddle, it's not caused by a bad `<DOCTYPE>`...

Comment: So, yeah, just use `padding` instead of `margin`.  Not sure `padding` makes sense on an image, but hey, we're talking IE here. Still wondering why this bug is still in IE10 though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use display:inline-block; on the anchor link or use padding-right on the image instead of margin and it will work in IE

Answer (score 1):

Replace `margin` with `padding`

`a img {padding-right:30px}`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, but did already use padding in the overlaying element. Setting `background-image` to a nonexistend file (`url(filedoesnotexist)`) or a transparent pixel did work for me.